# how to create progress/error view in dagger2 MVVM?

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I'm using Dagger2, Retrofit & following MVVM pattern in an application. 
I want to show progress bar while the page is loading & error message for network error or any data related issues. in my current implementation without Dagger, I've created a custom view & added that in each fragment with visibility gone & showing when needed. that view takes the context of activity & view to inflate as constructor parameters. is there any better way to display full-screen error page rather than adding a custom view in each fragment?

Comment: yes , use a SnackBar

Comment: I want to show errors in full screen mode .. errors can be "No item in cart" or "No internet Connection"